# Laravel Dependency Injection, using setting function

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Firstly I would like to apologize if it's a duplicated or repeating question.

I'm "new" to dependency injection.
I understood how I do it in __constructor functions but not sure about setter function.
I wanna use DI correctly, the question is: am I using it the right way in the following code:

```
public function setNotification(Notification $notification)
{
    $this->notification = $notification;
}

public function handle(PostWasCommented $event)
{
    $post = $event->comment->post;

    $post->load('blog');

    $followers = $post->followers;

    $online_ids = Redis::pipeline(function($pipe) use ($event, $followers, $post)
    {
        foreach($followers as $follower){
            if(Auth::id() != $follower->user_id){
                $this->setNotification(new Notification());
                $this->notification->from_id = Auth::id();
                $this->notification->to_id = $follower->user_id;
                $this->notification->type = 'PostComment';
                $this->notification->source_id = $event->comment->id;
                $this->notification->parent_id = $event->comment->post_id;
                $this->notification->blog_name = $post->blog->link_name;

                if($post->user_id == $follower->user_id)
                    $this->notification->my_post = true;
                else
                    $this->notification->my_post = false;

                $this->notification->save();

                $pipe->get('user'.$follower->user_id);
            }
        }
    });
```

---

I found out using mass assignment can can help me out :)

Comment: I'm not sure I see the dependency injection here.  The only thing that _may_ qualify is the `PostWasCommented` argument, but I don't think that's what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Injection, as the name suggests, only makes sense if the dependency is injected *from outside*.

Instead, what you have is a setter injection method `setNotification()` which you call from *within the same class* with `new Notification()` object as argument.

There is no injection going on. Your class is still tightly coupled with `Notification` and the `setNotification()` method serves no purpose.

Comment: How should I do it? assuming I want to inject new Notification each time the foreach loop runs...

Comment: If your object needs to consume a bunch of `Notification` objects, then the proper way would be creating a notification factory object and injecting that instead.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I would love to get a more elaborated answer. the solution I found, and will use is more built in the framework Laravel - Mass Assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, thanks a lot for all the information :)

```
public function __construct(Notification $notification)
{
    $this->notification = $notification;
}

public function handle(PostWasCommented $event)
{
    $post = $event->comment->post;

    $post->load('blog');

    $followers = $post->followers;

    $online_ids = Redis::pipeline(function($pipe) use ($event, $followers, $post)
    {
        foreach($followers as $follower){
            if(Auth::id() != $follower->user_id){

                $my_post = false;
                if($post->user_id == $follower->user_id)
                    $my_post = true;

                $this->notification->create([
                    'from_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'to_id' => $follower->user_id,
                    'type' => 'PostComment',
                    'source_id' => $event->comment->id,
                    'parent_id' => $event->comment->post_id,
                    'blog_name' => $post->blog->link_name,
                    'my_post' => $my_post
                ]);

                $this->notification->save();

                $pipe->get('user'.$follower->user_id);
            }
        }
    });
```

Mustn't forget to add $fillable array in the model.

```
 protected $fillable = ['from_id', 'from_id', 'to_id', 'type', 'source_id', 'parent_id', 'blog_name', 'my_post'];
```